# command to Stop infinite loop ??

Tags: python-3.x, loops, user-interface, button, breakout

I'm developing a graphical interface, i want to have the ability to pause or cancel this file after sending it. 
There are three buttons (Send, pause & stop), i already have done the function of the send button, I have to define now the function of the two button pause and cancel, How i do please ? 
here is the program

```
def moh():


# Open grbl serial port
s = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0',115200)

# Open g-code file

f = open(file_path.get(), "r");

# Wake up grbl
s.write("\r\n\r\n".encode('utf8'))
time.sleep(2)   # Wait for grbl to initialize 
s.flushInput()  # Flush startup text in serial input

# Stream g-code to grbl
for line in f:
    l = line.strip() # Strip all EOL characters for consistency
    print ('Sending: ' + l)
    s.write((l + '\n').encode("utf8")) # Send g-code block to grbl
    grbl_out = s.readline().decode("utf8") # Wait for grbl response with carriage return
    print (' : ' + grbl_out)

# Wait here until grbl is finished to close serial port and file.
raw_input("  Press <Enter> to exit and disable grbl.") 

# Close file and serial port
f.close()
s.close()

b1= Button(Outil, text ="Send",background='White', command=moh)
```

Thanks to all

Answer (score -1):

The command used to end a infinite loop is break()